# Huge plotly html

Tags: python, html, plotly, size, histogram

I've this simple plotly python script:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

s = np.random.normal(0., 1., 100000)

fig = px.histogram(s, nbins=7)
fig.write_html('fig.html', include_plotlyjs='cdn', full_html=False)
```

This is producing a basic histogram made of 7 bins:

[image: histogram]

However the html written is huge, 1.9Mo !

Why such a simple figure is so heavy ? Seems the 100000 random floats are included into the html file. But I just want to write the figure without the data. Is it possible? (and I don't want to write an image, I want to keep plotly figure interactivity)

Thanks a lot !

Xixi

Comment: The histogram is created on the clientside using Plotly.js so yes all the data are included in the html. Though, you can use `numpy.histogram()` to bin the data and count the number of values in each bin, and from there create a simple bar chart (as described [here](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#accessing-the-counts-yaxis-values)) which would drastically reduce the figure size (only the bins/counts data would be passed to the frontend).